# How to mark certain frames in Flash CS5 timeline?

Tags: adobe-flash, timeline

I'm using Flash CS5 and the timeline's gone really long. I need to access certain keyframes again and again, can I colorcode them or in any way mark them so I can quickly go back to them?
Does any such thing exist?